# D3 events on path don't work

Tags: javascript, html, events, d3.js, svg

Here is what i do:

```
var path = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data).sort(null))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .append("path").style("stroke-width", 0)
    .on("click", function(d){console.log(d)})
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", color)
    .style("opacity", function(d){ return(d.data.name == "ess")?0.6:1})
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i){ alert(1);})
    .on("mouseout", animateSecondStep);
```

but none of these event is firing

[This is what i get in events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AeNY.png)

Here is JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4pmdaaaz/1/

Comment: do you have a fiddle we can see ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy yes, sorry, completely forgot about it. https://jsfiddle.net/4pmdaaaz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this line :

```
document.getElementById(element).innerHTML += "<div class='result visible'><div class='giant-text' style='font-size:32px;'>" + precentage + "%</div> </div>";
```

Was messing with the interactions. Works without it, updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/4pmdaaaz/3/

Its due to you changing the `innerHTML` of the element with id 'first', which is the container of the pie chart. I definitely recommend not using innerHTML and use textContent instead. But in this case, I recommend making a new div and changing the style of that div to show, in this case, the 33% :)

Hope that helps

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. I changed it to appendChild and it works. Thanks again.

Comment: no problem :)) glad i could help. I recommend comparing to other examples and see what is different between your code and theirs. Makes it easier to spot mistakes :)